# count items from Scanner

Tags: java

I have declared a `Scanner` object named Scan

I want to prompt the user to enter however many items they like:

```
ie: Enter items: 1 2 6 4 3 12
```

how do I count how many numbers were entered? For example, the output from above should be 6, since there are 6 numbers

I have tried

```
int count = 0;
while(Scan.hasNextInt()){
count++ };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the line on whitespace and get the number of parts.

```
final String line = Scan.nextLine();
if(line.trim().isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Nothing entered");
} else {
    final String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(parts.length);
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/zgr6zM

To convert the parts to an int array, you can use `Arrays.stream` and `.mapToInt`.

```
final int[] nums = Arrays.stream(parts).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/WevrTw

Comment: part2: how can I store the items from that input into an array?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for the reminder. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in numbers as follows.

```
2 3 12 3 1 2
2 29 122 q
```

The main point is that `hasNextInt` will continue reading from the console until a non-integer is entered.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> numbs = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("Enter ints followed by any letter to quit");
while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
   numbs.add(scan.nextInt());
}

System.out.println("The following " + numbs.size() + " numbers were entered.");
System.out.println(numbs);
```

The above sample input would print.

```
The following 9 numbers were entered.
[2, 3, 12, 3, 1, 2, 2, 29, 122]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call `scanner.nextInt()` or your scanner's "pointer" will never move past the first number.

```
jshell> while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
   ...> count++;
   ...> scanner.nextInt();
   ...> }
1 2 3 4 5 6



jshell> count
count ==> 6
```

Comment: Love getting downvoted for writing the only comment that actually mentions the reason why OP's code doesn't work.